# How to prevent a table data element from overflowing outside my table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have an html table with 14 columns and 11 rows. Each td element has a specific id associated with it that correlates to the column and row. For example the 3rd column and 2nd row would be `<td id="3-2"></td>`. I'm querying a database that has information which goes into each td based on what day the user chooses on a datepicker. If that data meets a certain criteria, I set the rowspan attribute on my td element to "2". The problem is when I do that a `<td>` gets pushed to the outside of the table. Here is my js so you can get an idea of what I'm doing. The most important part of this starts at the for loop

```
function createAppointments() {
        //clear the dom with the clearTags() function so appointments don't overlap
        clearTags();
        //get all of the appointments that are related to the current day. Create a date variable equal to the datepicker value
        let myDate = document.getElementById('myDate');
        let day = myDate.value;
        console.log(day);
        //update the h1 element to display the current date
        document.getElementById('date').innerText = day;
        //use day in a doquery to query appts where fid 14(appointment date) is equal to the datepicker value
        let appts = qdb.DoQueryWithQueryString(apptsDBID,"{'14'.'EX'.'"+ day + "'}","3.6.18.17.11.37.39.41.42.43.44")//6-appt time/18-service/17-patient/11-trainer/37-element id/39-duration number/41-hex code/42 - notes/43 - top/ 44- left
    
    let records = qdb.selectNodes(appts,"*/table/records/record");
    //now we have our xml tree of all of our appointment records
    //loop through each record. The element id is a field in quickbase(37) which automatically takes the trainer name and appends a "-" and the start time of the appointment, which corresponds with the td ids.
    for(var i=0;i<records.length;i++) {
     debugger;
     let rec = records[i];
     let patient = gf(rec,17);
     let service = gf(rec,18);
     let notes = gf(rec,42);
     let textToDisplay = `${patient}-${service}`;
     let eid = gf(rec,37);
     let rid = gf(rec,3);
     let rspan = gf(rec,39);
     let t = gf(rec,43); //top px
     let l = gf(rec, 44);//left percentage
     console.log(`top is ${t} and left is ${l}`);
     let p = document.createElement("p");//create a new paragraph element to put in the table data
     let q = document.getElementById(eid);
     q.appendChild(p);//append the created paragraph element to the td for the onmouseover event
     p.innerText = textToDisplay;
     p.setAttribute("id",rid);
     p.setAttribute("data-toppx",t);
     p.setAttribute("data-leftpercent",l);
     p.setAttribute("data-notes", notes);
     q.style.backgroundColor = gf(rec,41);
     q.style.borderRadius = "10px";
     q.style.width = "225px";
     p.style.fontWeight = "bold";
     q.style.paddingLeft = "15px";
     p.setAttribute("onmouseover","showNotes(this)");//set the show notes function as an attribute of the paragraph
     p.setAttribute("onmouseleave","hideNotes()");//hide the notes div when not hovered 
     q.setAttribute("rowspan",gf(rec,39));}//set the row span attribute based on the rspan field in quick base
    }
    
    function showNotes(obj) {
        let contents = obj.dataset.notes;
        let topPX = obj.dataset.toppx;
        let leftP = obj.dataset.leftpercent;
        console.log(obj);
    let notes = document.querySelector('#notes');
    notes.style.visibility = "visible";
    notes.innerHTML = contents;
    console.log(topPX);
    console.log(leftP);
    notes.style.top = topPX;
    notes.style.left = leftP;
}

function hideNotes() {
    let notes = document.querySelector('#notes');
    notes.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

How can I prevent `<td>`s from being pushed outside my table? FYI the table is built statically not dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some css to your table like setting the table-layout to fixed and for td
word-wrap to break-word

Something like this
td { word-wrap: break-word; } table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }